# I am trying to connect to my azure managed instance(configured fail over group) using listener end point from SSMS

Tags: azure, failover, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have my data migrated to managed instance and configured fail over group. But not able to connect to my database using SSMS .I have also tried connecting by giving database name in options

Error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)
>
> ---
>
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failover group listener endpoint is basically a DNS record pointing to the private IP address of the current primary of failover group. The error message indicates that there is no network path between the client machine running SSMS and managed instance injected into your VNet within your private IP address space.
Given this error message I would expect that you cannot connect from the same client machine even using fully-qualified name of the instance itself.
Do you have P2S, S2S or Express Route established between the two locations?

Comment: yes , now i am able to connect using string after establishing S2S between SSMS and VNet. Thank you

Comment: hey can u please review my this question and help in resolving it. Thank you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067684/sometime-we-need-to-open-encryption-key-manually-after-failover-and-sometime-not